# Manga about a girl who witnesses an execution

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is about a girl who witnesses an execution of an evil woman. Later in the story, she was set up by her fiancee and the evil woman before possessed her body to save her.

Comment: This is very terse can you remember anything else about it? When did you read it? Why did her fiancée set her up? Why was the evil woman after her? Why did she save her? How did the possession work? If you remember anything else you can [edit] your question to add those details in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly [The Holy Grail of Eris](https://mangadex.org/title/42822/the-holy-grail-of-eris). The main character, Constance Grail, sees the execution of a noblewoman as a child.

> Constance, the daughter to a Viscount whose only value is her honesty, and Scarlet Castiel, the most reviled villainess of the era who was sentenced to death ten years ago. When the two people who were never supposed to meet encountered one another at a night party, the story that should have ended with Scarlet's death began anew.

> Although their relationship only began out of mutual interest, they soon became true partners in an effort to unravel the mysteries of a grand conspiracy borne out of the past, that still has a vicious grip on the present. (from the Mangadex description)

I don't remember the exact details of the "set up" but she does encounter her fiancee kissing another woman while at a party. I believe she's set up by the woman hosting the party, not her fiancee, but the basic details are the same. She is then possessed by the ghost of the executed noblewoman, who uses her guile and force of personality to turn the situation around to Constance's favor.

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for. Thank you so much.